# Error while executing broadleaf startadmin.bat script

Tags: java, heap-memory, broadleaf-commerce

I am new to Broadleaf Ecommerce and have installed the same couple of days back. Maven build is successful however getting below error while starting Startadmin.batch file. I have tried increasing heap memory however it didn't help. Any of you faced similar error?

> Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing :
>   target/agents/spring-instrument .jar
>   Error occurred during initialization of VM agent library failed to
>   init: instrument
>   Error occurred during initialization of VM Too small initial heap
>   Error occurred during initialization of VM Too small initial heap
>   ERROR: Cannot load this JVM TI agent twice, check your java command
>   line for dup licate jdwp options.
>   Error occurred during initialization of VM agent library failed to
>   init: jdwp

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to indicate that Spring-instruments.jar file was not downloaded. That means that your local maven failed on the "@copy-agent" goal that is responsible for installing that jar in the correct directory. Try doing a `mvn install` with Maven 3.3.9 and turning on the `@echo` when running the bat script to make sure that jar is installed.

Also change the `%TOMCAT_MEMORY%` line to be this:

```
IF "%TOMCAT_MEMORY%"=="" SET TOMCAT_MEMORY=-Xmx1536M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M
​
```

This will change the Heap size from 1536 bytes to a more suitable size.